# Big binary number

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to solve a problem, for the basic scenario it's working, nevertheless, I know that it is not optimal and has several faults.

Problem:
You are given a number n. Find the decimal value of the number formed by the concatenation of the binary representation of the first n positive integers. Print the answer 10^9 + 7.

Output format:
Print the answer modulo 10^9 + 7

Constraint:
1 <= n <= 10^9

```
Sample input: 3
Sample Output: 27
The binary representation of 1: 1
The binary representation of 2: 10
The binary representation of 3: 11
Concatenated string: 11011 -> Decimal representation is 27.
```

The first doubt that I have is: "modulo 10^9 + 7", I understand is the limit for the number of chars, but I don't know how to interpret it.

The second part of the question is with the solution:
Input: 20

```
Binary representation of 2 : 10.
Binary representation of 3 : 11
Binary representation of 4 : 100. 
Binary representation of 5 : 101
Binary representation of 6 : 110
Binary representation of 7 : 111
Binary representation of 8 : 1000
Binary representation of 9 : 1001
Binary representation of 10 : 1010
Binary representation of 11 : 1011
Binary representation of 12 : 1100
Binary representation of 13 : 1101
Binary representation of 14 : 1110
Binary representation of 15 : 1111
Binary representation of 16 : 10000
Binary representation of 17 : 10001
Binary representation of 18 : 10010
Binary representation of 19 : 10011
The binary representation of 20: 10100
Concatenated string: 11011100101110111100010011010101111001101111011111000010001100101001110100
```

How would you recommend to tackle this kind of problem?

This is my current code:

```
public long FindBigNum(long n) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Input: " + n);
    StringBuilder binaryRepresentation = new StringBuilder();
    for(Long i = 1l; i <= n; i++){
        System.out.println("Binary representation of " + i + " : " + Long.toBinaryString(i));
        binaryRepresentation.append(Long.toBinaryString(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Concatenated string: " + binaryRepresentation.toString());
    //System.out.println("Binary representation: " + binaryRepresentation.toString());
    long longRepresentation = parseLong(binaryRepresentation.toString(), 2);
    //System.out.println("longRepresentation: " + l);
    return longRepresentation;   
}

public long parseLong(String s, int base){
    return new BigInteger(s, base).longValue();
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Thanks for stopping by and letting us know of your task. We are not going to tell you how to solve it but will be glad to help you with your solution if you show us what you have tried and what doesnt work.

Comment: @JAsgarov - I appreciate your comment, I edited my original questions and added my current code.
My doubt is to implement the (10^9) + 7 and handle correctly big binary strings to decimals.
Finally, when I add a number that will give me a big string, like 100, the result will be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class TestClass {

```
static long FindBigNum(long n) {
    long result = 0;
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    long binarySumLong;
    long moduloFactor = (long) (Math.pow(10, 9) + 7);

    for (int number = 1; number < n; number++) {
        System.out.println("Number is : " + number);
        String binaryRepresentation = Long.toBinaryString(number);
        System.out.println("Binary representation of " + number + " is " + binaryRepresentation);
        binary.append(binaryRepresentation);
        System.out.println("Value of StringBuffer binary is " + binary);

        binarySumLong = binaryToInteger(binary.toString());
        System.out.println("binarySumLong is : " + binarySumLong);
        if (binarySumLong > (moduloFactor)) {
            binarySumLong = binarySumLong % (moduloFactor);
            binary = new StringBuilder(Long.toBinaryString(binarySumLong));
            System.out.println(" *** binary after modification is : " + binary);
            System.out.println(" *** and integer value of binary is : " + binaryToInteger(binary.toString()));
        }
    }

    result = binaryToInteger(binary.toString());
    return result;
}

public static int binaryToInteger(String binary) {
    char[] numbers = binary.toCharArray();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (numbers[i] == '1')
            result += Math.pow(2, (numbers.length - i - 1));
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long output = FindBigNum((long) Math.pow(10, 4));
    System.out.println("output is : " + output);
}
```

}

Comment: please explain how to solve the problem with this code.

Comment: 1. Get modul moduloFactor; 2. Iterate until we reach the number: i < n; 2.1 Get the binary representation of the number i; 2.2 Append the binary representation to StringBuilder; 2.3 binarySumLong = Get the integer representation of the binary representation; 2.4 If the integer representation > moduloFactor; 2.4.1 binarySumLong = integer representation % moduloFactor; 2.4.2 binary = get binary from binarySumLong; 3. Result = get integer from binary

Comment: Hello @Sanket Jain!
This is a clever approach.
How the moduloFactor was implemented it was part of my original doubt.
The reason of set a new value to binary all eligible iterations will be because binarySumLong will have the latest integer representation, am I right?

Comment: @ovatleyva Sorry I did not understand your doubt. What does, "The reason of set a new value to binary all eligible iterations will be" mean?

Comment: @SanketJain, in line 14 you set a value to binarySumLong and you do it again in line 17, this if the binarySumLong > moduloFactor and you will set the latest binaryString value to "binary" variable in line 18, that is cool and this does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

> The first doubt that I have is: "modulo 10^9 + 7", I understand is the limit for the number of chars, but I don't know how to interpret it.

That means to get the remainder when dividing by that value. It is the value `1000000007` (I am assuming the caret is exponentiation).

Here is how I would approach this.

- Generate your concatenated strings as you have been.
- Use `BigInteger` to convert from binary to decimal and then take the `mod` with the BigInteger `mod` method.

That will ultimately be very slow and not efficient.  However, it serves as a control to allow you to investigate optimal ways of doing it.  Perhaps employing StringBuilder and pre-allocating storage for it.  Writing your own int to binary conversion routine, etc.
It may even require more of a math solution (e.g. number theory) than a programming solution.

But you can compare your results to the BigInteger solution to verify if it is working.

Comment: Hello @WJS, thank you so much for your comment!.
Your assumption is correct, caret it's exponential.
I edited my initial comment and added my code, I did something very similar to what you have mentioned.
In order to implement 10 ^ 9 + 7, would I need to take the 
`- BigInteger subStringEnd = binaryRepresentation.length() % (10^9 + 7)
- Do a substring of the binaryRepresentation: binaryRepresentation.substring(0, subStringEnd)
- That should be the number to pass into the function to convert it to a decimal number?`

Comment: That would work but I didn't expect a bit string of a length > 10^9 bits.  So I don't know the exact requirements of the assignment.